# electron-rebuild grpc build failure

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp, grpc

When i try to run electron-rebuild to get grpc working for Electron, i get the below error.  When my colleague does the same thing, no error. We are unable to determine what the difference is in our environments.  Both Windows 10 64, node64, VS2015 package 3, "electron": "1.6.6", "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.7"

Any ideas? The error isn't telling me much.

```
C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client>npm run rebuild

> @ rebuild C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client
> electron-rebuild -m ./app

× Rebuild Failed
An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\app\node_modules\grpc\build\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj]

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Dev\\Projects\\Electron\\PAT\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.6.6" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Dev\\Projects\\Electron\\PAT\\client\\app\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary" "--host=https://storage.googleapis.com/" "--remote_path=grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/{name}/v1.2.3" "--package_name=electron-v1.6-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\app\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v7.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\app\node_modules\grpc\build\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj]

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Dev\\Projects\\Electron\\PAT\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.6.6" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Dev\\Projects\\Electron\\PAT\\client\\app\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary" "--host=https://storage.googleapis.com/" "--remote_path=grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/{name}/v1.2.3" "--package_name=electron-v1.6-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\app\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v7.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:262:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:236:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:197:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:128:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:102:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:128:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:102:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:236:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:236:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:185:22)
    at Subscriber._next (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:125:26)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:89:18)
    at ReduceSubscriber._complete (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\operator\reduce.js:119:30)
    at ReduceSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:114:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.notifyComplete (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\operator\mergeAll.js:105:30)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (C:\Dev\Projects\Electron\PAT\client\node_modules\rxjs\InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are looks like the same one that was reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10458). Basically, there's an action in gRPC's binding.gyp file that doesn't work correctly in the Windows 10 console.

Comment: Are you aware of a workaround? I wonder why my colleague's console works, we are both on Windows 10.

Comment: It's not great, but if you temporarily downgrade electron to 1.4, you should be able to get the gRPC precompiled binary for electron and bypass the gyp file entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, came across this with a similar error. Turned out being an issue with the cli I was using. Gitbash and command prompt both failed, but powershell as admin worked. For anyone else suffering, I hope you find this and build successfully.